# javascript animation slowed by elements over it

Tags: javascript, animation, png

I have come across a very mystifying problem in one of my animation loops. basically i have an animation running behind a PNG mask to create a glowing effect. the animation runs endlessly, as it is supposed to. But, after a short time, the animation slows down and eventually grinds to a halt.

here is the mystifying part: without the png mask (and the div its in), ***the animation runs smoothly.***

what is going on here?

--here is the page without the mask: http://chrismorga.com/rainnav/closed.html

--with the mask (reload and immediately watch the glow for slowdown): http://chrismorga.com/rainnav/open.html

for reference, here is the javascript. function runs after page load:

```
function StartMove() {
var cssBGImage=new Image();
cssBGImage.src="img/blueshifter.jpg";

window.cssMaxWidth=cssBGImage.width;
window.cssXPos=0;
setInterval("MoveBackGround()",10);
}

function MoveBackGround () {
window.cssXPos=window.cssXPos+1;
    if (window.cssXPos>=window.cssMaxWidth) {
    window.cssXPos=0;
    }
toMove=document.getElementById("scroller");
toMove.style.backgroundPosition=window.cssXPos+"px 0px";
}
```

...

```
<body onload="StartMove()">
```

Is my javascript utilizing some bad practice? any insight would help at this point.

Comment: Can you show us the part where you call StartMove?

Comment: Hans: Its in the first provided link: `<body onload="StartMove()">`

Comment: Opera 12/Linux animates slower, Firefox 13/Linux faster, but both don't stop animating and continue with constant animating speed. Maybe you try CSS3 features. Anyway, it is a big image to animate.

Comment: what are the specs of the computer that you are seeing the problem on? Works fine in chrome

Comment: Works fine and smooth for me in Firefox, chrome, Opera Konqueror...

Comment: by some sort of dark magic, i am still lagging here, on a 1st gen core i7 paired with 8gb of ram. anyway, my question was really, what is a better way to get the same animation effect and save memory? this is obviously inefficient and my final plan involves retina- size screens

Answer (score 0):

**-UPDATE-**

I found my problem by sheer happenstance. my cellphone ran the animation fine, so i thought, why this chrome and not the computer chrome?

as it turns out, **running chrome 19 was causing the errors!** quick update and i was running fine. i should welcome myself to the bleeding edge i guess, lol.